# How to simulate a fn key in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, drivers, keyboard

I have a keyboard that turns on the back lights using <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> (a button next to print screen), it works in Windows.

On Ubuntu however, it doesn't work. How can I simulate the pressing of this key? is it even possible?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/showkey ?

Comment: what laptop brand/model is it